# import ncurses.h problem in Mac, C programming

Tags: c, ncurses

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xfb0p.png)

Hi, this is my first post on stack overflow. I really need help on getting import <ncurses.h> to my vscode, but when I use getch()gives me this error. Please help me out.

Comment: those are linker errors. did you install ncurses on the mac ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're compiling with **gcc**, you have to add `-lncurses` flag at the end while compiling.

Example:

`gcc yourfile.c -lncurses`